# SkiaSharp convert SVG to PNG - image doesn't fit the canvas size entirely

Tags: c#, .net, skiasharp

I'm trying to convert a SVG image to PNG using SkiaSharp and return a PdfSharp XImage object with the image so I could add it to the PDF page (since PdfSharp doesn't directly support SVG format).

This is my code:

```
private XImage LoadSvgIcon(string iconUrl)
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load(iconUrl);

    using (Stream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        root.Save(xmlStream);
        xmlStream.Flush();
        xmlStream.Position = 0;
                
        var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
        svg.Load(xmlStream);
                
        var bitmap = new SKBitmap((int)svg.CanvasSize.Width, (int)svg.CanvasSize.Height);
        var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
                
        var p = new SKPaint();
        p.Color = SKColor.Parse("#219de1");
        canvas.DrawPaint(p);

        canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);

        using (var skData = SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100))
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            skData.SaveTo(stream);
            return XImage.FromStream(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Even though I set the size of the canvas as the size of the SVG, the SVG doesn't take the entire space of the canvas (the canvas can be seen with the bluish background and the SVG itself has the red background and the icon inside it - you can see that it doesn't take the entire canvas space).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Might try switch from deprecated `Extended.Svg` to `Svg.Skia` nuget.
You would want to scale the svg to fill the needed canvas size, the procedure is practically same as for scaling a loaded bitmap to fill the canvas, many examples out there.
Just some code, to illustrate the idea:

```
        if (Svg != null) // this is your loaded svg
        {
            SKMatrix matrix = CreateSvgMatrix(area, scale); //SKRect area you wont to use/fill
            
            using (var paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                paint.IsAntialias = true;

                //could also tint the svg:
                paint.ColorFilter = SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(TintColor.ToSKColor(), SKBlendMode.SrcIn); 

                ctx.Canvas.DrawPicture(Svg.Picture, ref matrix, paint);
            }
        }


    SKMatrix CreateSvgMatrix(SKRect destination, double scale)
    {

        #region Layout

        SKRect contentSize = Svg.Picture.CullRect;
        float scaledContentWidth = (float)(contentSize.Width); 
        float scaledContentHeight = (float)(contentSize.Height); 

        //multipliers to reduce
        float xRatio = destination.Width / scaledContentWidth;
        float yRatio = destination.Height / scaledContentHeight;

        var aspectX = xRatio;
        var aspectY = yRatio;
        var adjustX = 0f;
        var adjustY = 0f;

        if (Aspect == TransformAspect.Fill)
        {

            //multipliers to enlarge
            if (destination.Width > scaledContentWidth && aspectX < 1)
            {
                aspectX = 1 + (1 - aspectX);
            }
            if (destination.Height > scaledContentHeight && aspectY < 1)
            {
                aspectY = 1 + (1 - aspectY);
            }

            adjustX = (destination.Width - scaledContentWidth * aspectX) / 2.0f;
            adjustY = (destination.Height - scaledContentHeight * aspectY) / 2.0f;

        }
        else
        if (Aspect == TransformAspect.AspectFill)
        {
            var needMoreY = destination.Height - scaledContentHeight * xRatio;
            var needMoreX = destination.Width - scaledContentWidth * yRatio;
            var needMore = Math.Max(needMoreX, needMoreY);
            if (needMore > 0)
            {
                var moreX = needMore / scaledContentWidth;
                var moreY = needMore / scaledContentHeight;
                xRatio += moreX;
                yRatio += moreY;
            }

            if (destination.Width < destination.Height)
            {
                aspectX = xRatio;
                aspectY = xRatio;
            }
            else
            {
                aspectX = yRatio;
                aspectY = yRatio;
            }

            adjustX = (destination.Width - scaledContentWidth * aspectX) / 2.0f;
            adjustY = (destination.Height - scaledContentHeight * aspectY) / 2.0f;


        }
        else //FIT
        {
            //keep aspect
            var aspectFit = Math.Min(xRatio / ZoomX, yRatio / ZoomY);

            var aspectFitX = (float)(aspectFit * ZoomX * Zoom);
            var aspectFitY = (float)(aspectFit * ZoomY * Zoom);

            if (yRatio == aspectFit) // was fit for by height, need to center x
            {
                adjustX = (destination.Width - scaledContentWidth * aspectFitX) / 2.0f;
            }
            else// was fit for by width, need to center y
            {
                adjustY = (destination.Height - scaledContentHeight * aspectFitY) / 2.0f;
            }

            aspectX = aspectFitX;
            aspectY = aspectFitY;
        }

        var matrix = new SKMatrix
        {
            ScaleX = aspectX,
            SkewX = 0,
            TransX = destination.Left + adjustX + (float)Math.Round(HorizontalOffset * scale),
            SkewY = 0,
            ScaleY = aspectY,
            TransY = destination.Top + adjustY + (float)Math.Round(VerticalOffset * scale),
            Persp0 = 0,
            Persp1 = 0,
            Persp2 = 1
        };

        return matrix;

        #endregion

    }
```